# what HttpContext.Current.Request["CarName"] != null, what it is doing?

Tags: c#, .net

I am modifying a subject line of code but did not get it. I was thinking `HttpContext.Current.Request` is read only and it return the url of request. Can we set value for `HttpContext.Current.Request["CarName"]` just like a variable or a session variable?

Please guide me what this line is doing.

Edit:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request["CarName"] != null){
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Can you post the line of code you're looking at and what you're trying to do?

Comment: `Request` is an entire object containing information about the request.. not just the URL. The indexer method returns data from a key-value-pair in `Request.QueryString`, `Request.Form`, etc..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead can you please see my edit code and guide please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexer method on the `Request` object looks up the `KeyValuePair`'s within `Request`'s members. It is important to note that `Request` is an entire object.. not just a URL.

ILSpy shows this as the implementation of the indexer method:

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        string text = this.QueryString[key];
        if (text != null)
        {
            return text;
        }
        text = this.Form[key];
        if (text != null)
        {
            return text;
        }
        HttpCookie httpCookie = this.Cookies[key];
        if (httpCookie != null)
        {
            return httpCookie.Value;
        }
        text = this.ServerVariables[key];
        if (text != null)
        {
            return text;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, your line of code is checking to see if "CarName" is a key contained in any of the above `KeyValuePair` members of the `Request` object.

Answer (score 0):

See [HttpContext.Request.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) (When looking for `x[]` syntax, lookup `x.Item`):

> Gets the specified object from the *QueryString*, *Form*, *Cookies*, or *ServerVariables* collections.

If a value with the given key is *not found* from one of the sources then `null` is returned. In this case, "CarName" is presumably supplied in a valid request (e.g. `../search?CarName=Rusty`) so the conditional might check for "no search conditions".

This is *not* the same as using sessions! [Sessions](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/) provide a generic mechanism to associated data (but *can* be backed by direct cookies) "per session". In any case, never directly trust user data obtained from the client as it can be spoofed.